# gnuplot how to take plot title from data file

Tags: gnuplot

i have two data sets e.g.

data1

```
1 2 3 6
3 4 4 9
5 6 5 2
```

data2

```
1 7
1 8
1 9
```

now i need to plot the first data file normally, namely

```
plot for [i=2:4] "data1" u 1:(column(i))
```

Now, the title of each line should be the numbers on the second column of the second datafile.

Any clue on this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the files in the shell, gnuplot can't read data from more than one file for a single plot.

```
plot for [i=2:4] "< echo $(cut -f2 -d' ' data2) && cat data1" \
    using 1:(column(i)) title columnheader(i-1)
```